# SystemVerilog case statement does not work

Tags: system-verilog

Anyone know why this case statement doesn't work:

```
int width;
width = 8;
case (width === 16)
  1'b0: begin
    // correct code
  end
  1'b1: begin
    // we end up here
  end
endcase
```

I am using VCS. I tried running this with DVE debugger, and the code worked correctly when running with the debugger. Also, this code is nested within another case statement, not shown here.

Comment: The simple example you gave works properly in both Incisive and Questa.  Did you try the simple example with VCS?  If you saw different behavior when running with the debugger it sounds like a tool bug.  How is 'width' defined?  A parameter or something else?

Comment: That's called an `if` statement, and I'd slap the guy who brought that code into a review.

Comment: is it possible there was a race condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't directly answer you question, but I think synopsys will not make that stupid mistake. If they did, please let me know.

In some language, the return value '0' means true, I am not sure it is the same here.

But to avoid this issue, I think the code can be changed to other ways:

One way:

```
case (width)
  16 : begin
  // correct code
  end
  default : begin
  // Other code
  end
endcase
```

Or:

```
if (width === 16) begin
    // correct code
end
```

Comment: Changing to an if-statement made it work. Yes, this issue is happening with VCS. However, this issue isn't deterministic. Things were working fine with that code until recently.